# PostgreSQL Horizontal scaling for "database per customer" cloud service

Tags: postgresql, docker, cloud, multi-tenant

I'm looking for the best way to serve thousands of PostgreSQL databases for application tier. Each database is used for a specific customer.
The goals are:
1. Serve as much databases on minimal hardware (reduce cost)
2. Support horizontal scaling (so I can add more servers as more customers join).
3. Move databases between servers to load balance the setup.
4. Be able to bill based on resource consumption.

My thoughts were:
1. Run each customer database in a dedicated PostgreSQL server running inside docker
2. Run single cluster serving multiple databases and use database scaling options.

I'll appreciate if people can share other alternatives or any experience with one of the above.
Or in other words, what is the best way to achieve the above.

Comment: Regarding the 4th point on billing for resource consumption. Have you checked some schedulers which would enable your customers to query your DBs and log the different transactions ? You would then be able to query the different transaction and apply your billing model. Some people are using this more in terms of CPU consumption but I guess it could be used in your situation as well. Would this be a viable option for you?

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you provide more data on such options? @XYZ123

Comment: The main objective of a scheduler is to control incoming workloads from users and manage their progress. From this source of information, you'll be able to collect information on utilization frequency, CPU core time used, ... 
Depending on your needs and the overall system, you may also be able to enforce some specific behavior to avoid any security issues or optimize performances.
Another added value is the ability to visualize your hardware utilization. You can then decide to increase/reduce the amount necessary.